# Detecting Mesh Geometry Irregularities in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, mesh

I am trying to create a function to detect mesh geometry irregularities — for instance, the mesh possibly contains a missing face or possible normal flip problem.

To detect the missing face, I utilized some AI tools and found that:

```
bool HasMissingFaces(Mesh mesh)
{
    int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
    int vertexCount = mesh.vertexCount;

    // Ensure that every index in triangles is within the valid range of vertices
    foreach (var index in triangles)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= vertexCount)
        {
            return true; // Missing face found
        }
    }

    return false; // No missing faces found
}
```

But this is not higlighting any problem in the mesh. What is the right way to detect missing face?
**Edit:**
Here are the picture demonstration. The house model front and back images given:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The code the AI gave you is nonsense. Out of bounds indices aren't a class of error that any decent mesh tool/procgen algorithm produces. You'll need to explain in more detail what counts as a "missing" face for your purposes. For instance, if I model Saturn's rings as a flat disc with a hole in the middle, is that hole "missing"? Or are you requiring all models to be "manifold" (i.e. no exposed edges/seams — the surface connects to itself in every direction)? [For evaluating the orientation of faces, you might find this past Q&A helpful](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/159379/39518)

Comment: I am not able to define it. But just updated some photos to show you.

Comment: Before you can detect flipped normals, you first have to define what a "flipped normal" actually is. For convex meshes that's trivial, because you just need to determine whether the normal faces the center or not. But for concave meshes not so much, because some triangles will intentionally face the center. And "missing faces" aren't trivial to tell apart from intentional holes either.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is probably not the right place to be doing this kind of detection, if you can avoid it.

The reason is that DCC tools like 3ds Max / Maya / Blender maintain a lot of metadata about how a shape is constructed and how its parts connect together, to support powerful geometry modifying operations.

When those meshes get imported into a game engine, all that extra data gets baked/stripped away to make the leanest, most efficient version for rendering. So what we see in the game data structures is just a "polygon soup" — just a big array of vertex data and indices to indicate which vertex triples form each triangle. In that form, it's hard to answer "is this face oriented the same way as the ones it's touching" because we don't *know* which ones it's touching.

Rebuilding this adjacency information is somewhat complex to code, expensive to run, error-prone, and won't be able to recover all the info the DCC tool it was authored in had.

So, I'd only try to do this in Unity if it has to happen *dynamically*, e.g.

- Players / modders need to be able to import custom meshes at runtime, and have them pass a validation check or auto-correction before they can be used in-game.
- If you have a procedural content generation algorithm running inside Unity that occasionally produces bad geo. (Though there, a better solution is to fix the algorithm, since it likely has better info about what it's doing than the polygon soup you get at the end)

In all other circumstances, it's more effective to solve this in your DCC tool of choice. [They'll often have specialized tools or user-made scripts for detecting/solving this kind of problem](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=blender+find+flipped+face&ia=web) (at least, the subset where we can tell the difference between an intentional and unintentional hole/flip in some algorithmic way), and you may even be able to use their scripting API to run these tools on batches of models, rather than inspecting each one by hand.

---

If you need to do this in Unity, here's a high-level overview of the steps it would take.

1. Iterate over the vertices and group them by position. During import/export, any vertex point on the mesh where there's a hard/creased edge or a texture mapping seam will be split into multiple vertices sharing the same position. We need to find all those discrete vertex indices referring to the same point and map them to one "logical" vertex ID.
2. Iterate over all the triangle indices to note which logical vertices they connect, in what order. Build a collection of oriented edges and the faces they border, keyed by the logical vertex indices they connect (you can use the "half-edge" data structure for this).
3. Check through this collection for multiple edges sharing the same pair of vertices (in the same or opposite order):

   - Only one edge connects this pair: this could be the border of a deliberate hole or "missing face" in your mesh. Or it could be on the outside border of a skirt mesh that doesn't close in on itself, like a ground plane. This can also occur if your mesh has T-junctions, where there's a "zero-width hole" between a big polygon and multiple smaller ones along a shared edge, but the surface looks unbroken.
   - Two edges connect this pair, with opposite orders: this is a "manifold" seam between two adjacent faces oriented the same way. This geo is probably fine.
   - Two edges connect this pair, with the same order: here we have two faces meeting but facing in opposite directions. It's very likely one of them is flipped relative to its neighbours.
   - Three or more edges: here you have non-manifold geometry with fins, and all bets are off as to what the artist intended here. You'll need manual inspection to determine whether it's as-desired.

Once you've found one of these edges at the border of a potential hole or flipped face, you can continue walking along connected edges to find which triangles are flipped relative to their neighbours (e.g. use the majority vote to determine which orientation is "right") or which triangles would need to be inserted to plug the hole, if your heuristics determine that it *is* a hole that needs plugging.